# condition between and string and json string

Tags: javascript, json

I trying to find the data type and convert to json.

need to escape double quotes and parse it, but conditionally.

between 2 responses one is needed as string and one is needed as json.

```
value = {response: "Hello, My Name is MoxBot"};

value = {response:
      "{
       "message":"here are the list of buttons",
       "component":{"html":"","buttons":["get balance","pay bill"]}
      }"
};
```

how to deal with this data.. the response will have double quotes that we can't change.

I tried this

```
value.response = value.response.slice(1, -1);
if(typeof value.response === 'object'){
            console.log("Obj");
            console.log(value.response);
        }else{
            console.log("Str");
            value.response = JSON.stringify(value.response);
            console.log(value.response);
        }
```

Comment: what you are trying to do its not clear

Comment: It's rather insane if you don't know whether a specific value needs to be decoded in some way or not. You're left guessing. While you can probably guess correctly most of the time, that is far from guaranteed. Having a fixed specification here is the real solution.

Comment: `value.response` is a string in both cases. JSON is text, so it nor a `slice()` of it wouldn't test as an `object`

Comment: where do these objects come from? can't you just JSON encode the text-answer to have a somewhat uniform format? Plus, why is there JSON insise an object? usually you build the entire object and encode it in the last moment just for the transport.

Comment: i understood but the response hold different type of data from now. if it need to change i need to change the core functionality.

Comment: @Thomas i tried to JSON.parse due to double quotes outside the json it was unable to parse

Comment: It is a processed response and always comes in a string format.. this json response requirement was new to this system.. i am trying to deal with this here itself.. if not possible need to add the core application's response with data type.

Comment: A valid response string for value.response should be this ("{\"message\":\"here are the list of buttons\",\"component\":{\"html\":\"\",\"buttons\":[\"get balance\",\"pay bill\"]}}") which can be easily parsed with JSON.parse().